# MySQL/PHP Multilanguage form

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, translation

How can I build multilanguage form with Translations from database using pdo object?

for example, there is my code to create pdo object:

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMEssage();
    die();
}

$sql = "SELECT FROM `lang_content` `id`, `:lang`";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);

if($query->execute(array(
        ':lang' => $_GET['lang'].'_content'
    ))){
    // Show content
}
```

MySQL table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `lang_content` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `en_content` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `lv_content` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ru_content` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COMMENT='All translations'
ENGINE=MyISAM
;
```

MySQL table data example:

```
id  en_content  lv_content  ru_content
1   MOD         KASKO       КАСКО
2   MTPL        OCTA        ОСАГО
```

And I would like to use it like:
if lang en

```
<?= $result->1 ?> // Echo MOD
```

Will return MOD,

```
<?= $result->2 ?> // Echo MTPL
```

Will return MTPL

Answer (score 0):

Honestly that is not good practice to do your translation via database. Many big platforms do it through some sort of text format. For example magento does it through csv files.

You could start your development with the following code.

Your Spanish translation file `es.csv`

```
'Home', 'Inicio'
'Page 1', 'Pagina 1'
'Page 2', 'Pagina 2'
'Page 3', 'Pagina 3'
```

The first column of words would be your default language which would be defined within a function.

```
<a href="#"><?php __("Home"); ?>
```

Then you would use a switch statement like the one you have on top to capture which language the user choose. The `__()` function would look something like this. Where input would be "home"

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file));
// Logic (where it would do the translation)
// It could look for the input in the $cvs variable if it exist then use the next value of the current array. Else keep the text the same.
```

Your cvs file would need to make the exact words to be translated.

Comment: is it possible to add 3 languages into 1 csv file? and select column depends on what language are selected? Because I already have Excel file with translations

Comment: Its is possible but you need to create some kind of logic. I would recommend you do to in separate files because if you have large amount of translations in one file it can be  pain. it would be better if you had all the translation files separate based on their language in a dir called locale or what ever you wish to call it.